# How to become a registered market maker on an exchange

Tags: market-making, exchange, european, fees

We are thinking of applying to become a registered market-maker on different European exchanges. The name varies from exchange to exchange (Liquidity provider on Euronext for instance).
Could anybody tell me on say Euronext or LSE

1. how long does it take
2. what are the upsides/downsides
3. what are contractual requirements
4. do all the market makers on an exchange incur the same cost/reward or is it possible to "bargain" with the exchange.

I know that some exchanges signed special agreements with a few players giving them special fees.

Comment: this is not a quant related question

Comment: No... why should it be??? the forum is called Quantitative Finance not Quant questions on Finance

Comment: and how is your question related to Quantitative Finance in the slightest? It is as unrelated as asking "Is trading currencies cheaper through futures or cash fx"?

Comment: If you're seriously considering becoming a registered market maker, you should be talking to the exchange where you want to register. They will happily tell you the answers. Not on topic for this forum, IMO.